# Create a button that will initialize the page to a certain state

Tags: javascript, html

Initially my page has a couple of buttons and a table. After I can add/remove rows from the table. I want to create another button that will have initial state of the page, that is buttons and empty table.

My javascript:

```
function initialize_page() {
    localStorage.clear()
    var preambula = '<button type="button" id="create_row">Create row</button> \
                    <button type="button" id="remove_row">Delete row</button><br> \
                    <button type="button" id="initialize">New Table</button><br> \
                    <table id="main_table"> \
                      <tr> \
                        <td>#</td> \
                        <td>Name</td> \
                        <td>Pref.1</td> \
                        <td>Pref.2</td> \
                        <td>Pref.3</td> \
                      </tr> \
                    </table>'
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = preambula;
}
initialize_page();

document.getElementById('initialize').onclick = initialize_page;
```

However, it says:  `Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`.

My task is simple: I have initiale html, then I can add/remove rows, when I press initialize button I want to go back initial html. What is the easiest way to do this? (would like without using jQuery)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/75go0bow/2/

Answer (score 1):

You need something to append your created div element to.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = preambula;
document.getElementById('append-table').innerHTML = '';
document.getElementById('append-table').appendChild(div);
```

I created a fiddle for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/6x7jd5od/

Answer (score 1):

Your `initialize` element doesn't exist yet, as in, it isn't in the DOM, therefore `getElementById()` cannot find it.

This is because you create a a div element, that contains your `preambula` html, but you didn't append that div element anywheres in the DOM.

You need to add something like:

```
    document.body.appendChild(div);
```

inside your `initialize_page` function.

Answer (score 0):

the input is NOT in the document. The DIV you are creating only exists in JS, it's not added to the document anywhere.